# Как объединить массив объектов с одинаковым значением свойства?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов с кодом, видом услуги и суммой:

```
let Arr = [
{
serviceid: 1,
servicename : "Откопка ямы",
sum : 30
},
{
serviceid: 1,
servicename : "Откопка ямы",
sum : 50
},
{
serviceid: 2,
servicename : "Кладка плитки",
sum : 20
},
{
serviceid: 2,
servicename : "Кладка плитки",
sum : 25
},
{
serviceid: 3,
servicename : "Услуги трактора",
sum : 44
}
]
```

Видов услуг может быть много.
Необходимо посчитать сумму с одинаковыми serviceid и на выходе получить объединенный массив объектов:

```
[
    {
    serviceid: 1,
    servicename : "Откопка ямы",
    sum : 80
    },
    {
    serviceid: 2,
    servicename : "Кладка плитки",
    sum : 45
    },
    {
    serviceid: 3,
    servicename : "Услуги трактора",
    sum : 44
    }
    ]
```

Comment: [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) вам в помощь.

Comment: Понимаю, что задача для reduce. Уже полдня пытаюсь его приложить, не получается)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить 2 варианта для суммирования элементов массива и возврата нового массива с агрегированными элементами:

Вариант для больших массивов

```js
let Arr = [
  {
    serviceid: 1,
    servicename : "Откопка ямы",
    sum : 30
  },
  {
    serviceid: 1,
    servicename : "Откопка ямы",
    sum : 50
  },
  {
    serviceid: 2,
    servicename : "Кладка плитки",
    sum : 20
  },
  {
    serviceid: 2,
    servicename : "Кладка плитки",
    sum : 25
  },
  {
    serviceid: 3,
    servicename : "Услуги трактора",
    sum : 44
  }
];

function calcArr(arr) {
  const res = [];
  const resSum = {}
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (resSum[item.serviceid]) {
      resSum[item.serviceid].sum += item.sum;
    } else {
      resSum[item.serviceid] = {
        sum: item.sum,
        servicename: item.servicename
      }
    }
  });
  for (let x in resSum) {
    res.push({
      serviceid: +x,
      servicename: resSum[x].servicename,
      sum: resSum[x].sum
    })
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(calcArr(Arr));
```

Вариант для маленьких массивов

```js
let Arr = [
  {
    serviceid: 1,
    servicename : "Откопка ямы",
    sum : 30
  },
  {
    serviceid: 1,
    servicename : "Откопка ямы",
    sum : 50
  },
  {
    serviceid: 2,
    servicename : "Кладка плитки",
    sum : 20
  },
  {
    serviceid: 2,
    servicename : "Кладка плитки",
    sum : 25
  },
  {
    serviceid: 3,
    servicename : "Услуги трактора",
    sum : 44
  }
];

function reduceCalc(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const pos = acc.findIndex(it => it.serviceid === item.serviceid);
    if (pos === -1) acc.push(item)
    else acc[pos].sum += item.sum;
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

console.log(reduceCalc(Arr));
```

Времы выполнения:

| Элементов | Повторений | Время forEach+for | Время reduce |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10000 | 11.187ms | 3.74ms |
| 5 | 100000 | 63.639ms | 8.433ms |
| 1000 | 10000 | 88.678ms | 95.673ms |
| 1000 | 100000 | 862.047ms | 1.001s |
| 10000 | 10000 | 761.753ms | 1.631s |
| 10000 | 100000 | 7.529s | 16.435s |
| 100000 | 10000 | 7.563s | 17.191s |
| 100000 | 100000 | 1:14.519 (m:ss.mmm) | 3:02.386 (m:ss.mmm) |

Comment: Спасибо за решение! О вариантах я даже и не мечтал)

Comment: Вариант для маленьких массивов не нужен. В том плане что не нужно учить циклам в цикле, если можно обойтись без них, какая бы не была размерность массива :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

1. Создаём словарь - [new Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
2. Проходимся по элемнтам массива ([reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) и смотрим, если в словаре есть объект с данным `serviceid`, то достаём его и добавляем к сумме значение `sum` - `curr.sum += obj.sum`
3. Если нет, то добавлем новый элемент с суммой равной нулю - `groups.set(obj.serviceid, {...obj, sum: 0})`
4. Далее достаём из словаря все значения ([.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values)) и преобразуем их в массив с помощью синатксиса [[...]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const arr = [{
    serviceid: 1,
    servicename: "Откопка ямы",
    sum: 30
  },
  {
    serviceid: 1,
    servicename: "Откопка ямы",
    sum: 50
  },
  {
    serviceid: 2,
    servicename: "Кладка плитки",
    sum: 20
  },
  {
    serviceid: 2,
    servicename: "Кладка плитки",
    sum: 25
  },
  {
    serviceid: 3,
    servicename: "Услуги трактора",
    sum: 44
  }
];

const groupArr = [...arr.reduce((groups, obj) => {  
  if (!groups.has(obj.serviceid)) groups.set(obj.serviceid, {...obj, sum: 0});
  
  const curr = groups.get(obj.serviceid);
  
  curr.sum += obj.sum;
  
  return groups;  
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(groupArr);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает

Answer (score 2):

Кину и свой камень в огород, видимо господа программисты не знают что find возвращает по референсу, и можно запросто менять объект прям в внутри массива.

```js
let result = Arr.reduce((out, el, index, inp) => {
    /** где
     out - в первом шаге это 2й параметр функции reduce,в последующих то что возвращает return
     el - текущий элемент итерации
     index -  порядковое число текущего элемента el
     inp - сам массив целиком
    */
    let last = out.find(e => e.serviceid === el.serviceid)
    if (last) {
        last.sum += el.sum
    } else {
        out.push(el)
    }
    return out
}, [])
```

Задающему вопрос хочу сказать, что-бы вас не минусовали и вопрос был уместен. Во первых пожалуйста изучите хотя-бы `стандарты написания кода JS`

- Google JavaScript Style Guide
- JSCS

Ваш код выглядит ужасно!

Во вторых задавайте вопрос по существу - `не понимаю как работает reducer, поясните пожалуйста на моём примере`

Comment: "господа программисты не знают" - во первых с чего такое утверждение? Во вторых эту задачу можно решить разными способами. И то что вы предложили хуже по производительности того что уже было предложено "господами программистами". Цикл в цикле для такой простой задачи не нужен

Comment: К вашему сведению: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#description

Answer (score 0):

Предложу еще такой вариант... Всего один проход по массиву. Далее применяется объектный метод.

```js
let Arr = [
  {
  serviceid: 1,
  servicename : "Откопка ямы",
  sum : 30
  },
  {
  serviceid: 1,
  servicename : "Откопка ямы",
  sum : 50
  },
  {
  serviceid: 2,
  servicename : "Кладка плитки",
  sum : 20
  },
  {
  serviceid: 2,
  servicename : "Кладка плитки",
  sum : 25
  },
  {
  serviceid: 3,
  servicename : "Услуги трактора",
  sum : 44
  }
]
console.log(test(Arr))
//
function test(arr) {
  const obj = arr.reduce((obj, o) => {
    if (obj[o.serviceid]) obj[o.serviceid].sum += o.sum 
    else obj[o.serviceid] = {...o}
    return obj
  }, {})
  return Object.values(obj)
}
```